# How can I get the jQuery I worked on in jsfiddle to my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website mostly just for fun and am using HTML and CSS. I have some limited knowledge of these languages, but have never used jQuery before. But for only one page of the website, I wanted to have "linked sliders," which I found could be created using jQuery. I found a jsdiddle with some sliders and modified them to fit my project.

Here's the jsdiddle with the end product that I'd like to be embedded on one page of my site: http://jsfiddle.net/7e8xwjer/8/

I looked up how to add jQuery to a page, and took the following steps:

1) Downloaded jquery-1.12.3.js and renamed it jquery.js.

2) Added the following line of code in the head of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

3) Created a new .js file called js1.js with all the jQuery code from the jsdiddle.

4) Added the following line of code in the head of the page (in addition to the first):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
```

5) Added the CSS styling and HTML table from the diddle as needed.

The CSS and HTML table work fine, but none of the jQuery works. I'm sure I've made a simple error here, but I can't figure it out! Please let me know what other steps I need to take to get the jQuery script functioning on the site.

Thanks in advance for the patience and help.

Comment: Do you using IE as browser?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is using [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) in addition to JQuery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- no, renamed it to jquery.js . That was a typo, sorry. :)

Comment: @PhilRoss -- so in addition to doing what I've done, I'd download JQuery UI, name it appropriately, and include an additional script tag of `<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui.js"></script>` in the `head`?

Comment: What is the link to your site?

Comment: You'll need to include the JQuery UI Javascript and CSS. See https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle, usually, (depends on the settings you choose [see image, point 1]) encloses all JS code into a document ready event so your `js1.js` should look something like:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
    // your code from JSFiddle here
 });
```

**EDIT:**
looking at your Fiddle, you are using JqueryUI [see image, point 2] so have to include it as others said in comments.

**EDIT 2**
your fiddle is set "onLoad" [see image, point 3] so to reproduce exactly the same condition you would have to replace `$(document).ready` with `$(window).load`; however I'm not sure that in your case you need to wait until all resources are loaded... So don't change it unless needed.

[image]

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome! PS one last tip: when you include JQueryUI make sure that you include it after JQuery, or it won't work (the order is important in this case because JQueryUI depends on JQuery to function properly)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a library of functions.  You need to import them.  When you download the library, you need to point the `src=` correctly.  The directory where jquery is in relation to the overall file structure.

myharddrive
\ myfolders
  \ mysubfolders
  \ jquery
  index.html
  mycss.css
\ myfolders

`src=/jquery/jquery.min.js`

Comment: If my jquery.js file and my webpage are in the same folder, though, it would just be `src="jquery.js"` right?